# How to get the value of global variables imported from linker through gdb?

Tags: assembly, linker, gdb

Following global variables are imported into assembly file.

```
.global _sbss               /* Start of .bss in RAM */
.global _ebss               /* End+1 of .bss in RAM */
```

through gdb, how can I get these values?
When I tried print _ebss, I get the following:

```
(gdb) print _ebss
$1 = 106 'j'
```

I don't understand what above mean. I am expecting an address in the RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print the address of a symbol, use the take-address operator (`&`):

```
(gdb) print &_ebss
$1 = ...
```

Otherwise, gdb prints the value stored at the symbol's address.

Comment: (gdb) print &_ebss gives following: 
$2 = (<variable (not text or data), no debug info> *) 0x4c24a0 "j\205[\307x\231j\222\027\362\224\273T\031\274\r"

Comment: @sniper Isn't `0x4c24a0` the address you wanted?

Comment: @sniper: You could have used a `.type` directive or something to emit metadata marking the symbol as something that gdb wouldn't try to decode.  Don't use `void*` though, because that's probably more confusing.  (The value stored there isn't a `void*` or anything else, and you want to treat its *address* as a `void*`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You can declare the symbol as being of type `const void`. This is legal, though, crashes some compilers.

Comment: @FUZxxl: If you know the right syntax for declaring it that way, that would be a great addition to your answer.  I guess it's not actually `.type` that's needed, just debug info?  This [compiler output](https://godbolt.org/g/ocIhpE) isn't helping me figure it out from an example (with unsigned long long instead of void).

Comment: @PeterCordes That looks like manually written DWARF code. I have no idea how to do that in assembly. I think adding the type information at runtime in the debugger is the best choice.